# The square root of Wilson's theorem when $p\equiv 1 \mod 4$

Tags: nt.number-theory

My question relates, at least superficially, to these old ones:

[The value $\pm 1$ for the square root of Wilson's theorem, ((p-1)/2)! mod p](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121678/the-value-pm-1-for-the-square-root-of-wilsons-theorem-p-1-2-mod-p?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Primes P such that ((P-1)/2)!=1 mod P](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16141/primes-p-such-that-p-1-2-1-mod-p)

When $p\equiv 1 \mod 4$, if $x=((p-1)/2)!$, then $x^2 = -1 \mod p$.

For what primes does $x \in \{1,\ldots,(p-1)/2\}$ (the elements of the set regarded as residues $\mod p$)?

One gets "yes" for $5,13,29,41,53,61,73,89,97,\ldots$ and "no" for 
 $17,37,101,\ldots$.  Despite the slow start for "no", the counts substantially even out, say, when looking at primes up to 100000.  Can one prove that the ratio approaches $1/2$?

Comment: The first eight terms of your $5,13,29\dots$ match http://oeis.org/A185086 (but your 9th term is 97, instaed of 109).

Answer (score 20):

In the case $p \equiv 1$ mod $4$, the connection is to the *real* quadratic field ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{p})$, whereas the case $p \equiv 3$ mod $4$ is connected to the imaginary quadratic field ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{-p})$.

Chowla ("On the class number of real quadratic fields", 1961 PNAS) proves that
$$\left( \frac{p-1}{2} \right)! \equiv (-1)^{\frac{h+1}{2}} \cdot \frac{t}{2} \text{ mod } p,$$
where $h$ is the class number of ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{p})$ and the fundamental unit is $\frac{1}{2}(t + u \sqrt{p}) > 1$ with $t,u \in {\mathbb Z}$.

<s>In fact, 0 < t < 2p.</s>  EDIT:  that's false.  I think I was remembering a converse, that if you find such an element $\frac{1}{2}(t + u \sqrt{p})$ of norm $-1$, and $0 < t < 2p$, then it's a fundamental unit.  (This is right, I hope, but not so relevant).  See [Upper bound on answer for Pell equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229439/upper-bound-on-answer-for-pell-equation) for more on bounding $t$.

So it seems like the answer depends on (1) the class number mod 4 and (2) whether $\frac{t}{2} \in \{ 1,2,\ldots,\frac{p-1}{2} \}$ mod $p$.  The statistics seem (to me) at least as difficult as the $p \equiv 3$ mod $4$ case.

Comment: Do you have a reference on hand that $t<2p$?

Comment: According to the table at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalUnit.html, the fundamental unit when $p=73$ is $1068+125\sqrt{73}$, apparently in violation of $0<t<2p$.

Comment: Chowla's paper (p. 878 of the reference cited) does not claim $0<t<2p$.

Comment: Ahh - I messed up on that one.  I've made a correction, and sadly it makes the answer a bit weaker when we don't have such a nice bound on $t$.  It was too good to be true.

Comment: In light of the correction, I'll wait awhile and see if anyone upgrades the answer.  But thank you for the reference to Chowla!!!!

Comment: I’m curious to see if there’s a stronger result too!

Comment: There is a discussion of the case $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16141/primes-p-such-that-p-1-2-1-mod-p