# 1/2 Wilson's theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields

During my research I came across this question :

**Question:** What's the value of $x_p=(\dfrac{p-1}{2})! \mod p$ when $p>3$ is prime ?

*Remark:* It's easy to see $x_p^2 \mod p=(-1)^{\dfrac{p+1}{2}} \mod p$ with $x_p\in [1;p-1] \cap \mathbb N$

But it's not easy to find if $x_p \leq\dfrac{p-1}{2}$ or $x_p> \dfrac{p-1}{2}$

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121678/the-value-pm-1-for-the-square-root-of-wilsons-theorem-p-1-2-mod-p?rq=1

Comment: He talks about the case $p \mod 4=3$ what about the other case ?

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A004055](https://oeis.org/A004055) for programs and the first 9999 terms.

Comment: If you change the generator $b$ and replace it (for example) by $1/b$ then the sign you are interested in changes. So I think in the case p=1 mod 4, it does not really make sense to ask about this sign, as there is no canonical generator of $\mathbb{F}_p^{\times} $

Comment: Nevertheless you could define a kind of canonical square root of -1 by using a decomposition $p=a^2+b^2$, say $a/b$ with $a <b $. But you see it depends on some choices, which could turn out to be arbitrary

Comment: Maybe when $x_p<\dfrac{p-1}{2}$ ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the case $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, see the following paper of Chowla: On the class number of real quadratic fields. Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. U.S.A. 47 (1961), 878. There the following is proved:

Let $h$ be the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$, and let $\epsilon = (u+v\sqrt{p})/2$ be the fundamental unit of the corresponding ring of integers. Then $h$ is odd and
$$ 2\cdot \frac{p-1}{2}! \equiv (-1)^{(h+1)/2} u \pmod{p}.$$

One can find an exposition of this result (and related material) in the last chapter of Pollack's *Conversational Introduction to Algebraic Number Theory*.

Answer (score 7):

See [the paper by Mordell: The congruence (p−1/2)!≡±1 (mod p). Amer. Math. Monthly 68 1961 145–146](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2312481).

Comment: And $x_p=+-\sqrt{-1}$ when $p \mod 4=1$