# ((p-1)/2)! mod p

Tags: nt.number-theory

I came across the following question:

Is it known whether there exist infinitely many primes $p$ such that $\frac{p-1}{2}!\equiv_{p}1$?

(It is easy to see that if $p\equiv_{4}3$ then this number is $\pm 1$ mod $p$.)

Comment: Have a look at [this MO question and answer](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16141/primes-p-such-that-p-1-2-1-mod-p).